# What is correct way to make custom view based on EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

What is correct way to extend EditText?

The problem is following:

I have empty application from template with two EditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="one"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="two"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It works fine:

[image]

Then I create my custom view from EditText:

```
public class CuteEditText extends EditText {
    public CuteEditText(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CuteEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CuteEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        // some special initialization will be here
    }
}
```

And when I change EditText to my CuteEditText, interface works incorrectly:

[image]

The problem is not only with view ot UI. If I type something in first EditText and than touch the second one, nohing happens: input will continue in first.

The same behaviour if I inherite CuteEditText from AppCompatEditText.

What is wrong?

Sources for experiment are available at https://github.com/tseglevskiy/EditTextExperiment

Comment: you should pass `android.R.attr.editTextStyle` (instead of `0`) as the last parameter of `this(context, attrs, 0);` or just call `super` in all of your constructors

Answer (score 0):

Your construtors are broken. This is how it should look:

```
public class CuteEditText extends EditText {
    public CuteEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CuteEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CuteEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

Comment: They are broken for what OP wants : ).

Comment: Yes, EditText's default defStyleAttr is not 0. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the third constructor overload. The first one is for creating the view programmatically and the second one is for creating the view from xml. Those two should be enough for most cases.

```
public class CuteEditText extends EditText {
    public CuteEditText(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CuteEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```